# Template error regarding the choice of the structure

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having a problem with my structures... or something like that. I have 2 Arrays the one is defined as `Array <Student> DBst` and one  `Array <Assignment> DBas`. The thing is somewhere it get missed up because one of my function (in template form) pops an error  were it tells me `Class Assignment` has no function `setStudent(...)` but I don't know why it reads me struct `DBst` as an collection of Assigment objects.

Domain.h:

```
template <class T>
void addStudent(int a, int b, std::string c,Array <T> &A){
    A.M[a].setStudent(a,b,c);
    cout<<"here";
}
```

Controller.h:

```
template <class T1>
void _addStudent(Array <T1> &A){
    int a,b;
    string c;
    cout<<"Enter ID:"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Enter Group:"<<endl;
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"Enter Name:"<<endl;
    cin>>c;

    addStudent(a,b,c,A);
}
```

Menuc.cpp:

```
void Menu::mainMenu(Array <Student> &DBst,Array <Assignment> &DBas){
showMainMenu();
int ret = Menu::intInputHandler();

switch(ret){
case 1:studentMenu(DBst,DBas);break;
case 2:assignmentMenu(DBas,DBst);break;
case 3:statsMenu(DBst,DBas);break;
case 4:_printAll(DBst,DBas);break;
case 0:break;
default:cout<<"Wrong option selected!";break;
}
Menu::mainMenu(DBst,DBas);

    void Menu::studentMenu(Array <Student> &DBst,Array <Assignment> &DBas){
    showStudentMenu();
    int ret = Menu::intInputHandler();

    switch(ret){
    case 1:_addStudent(DBst);break;
    case 2:_removeStudent(DBst);break;
    case 3:_editStudent(DBst);break;
    case 4:_printStudent(DBst);break;
    case 5:_printAllStud(DBst);break;
    case 6:_searchByID(DBst);break;
    case 0:mainMenu(DBst,DBas);break;
    default:cout<<"Wrong option selected!";break;
    }
    Menu::studentMenu(DBst,DBas);
}
```

Menu.h:

```
class Menu{

    public:
        string stringInputHandler();
        int intInputHandler();
        void mainMenu(Array <Student> &,Array <Assignment> &);
        void studentMenu(Array <Student> &,Array <Assignment> &);
        void assignmentMenu(Array <Assignment> &,Array <Student> &);
        void statsMenu(Array <Student> &,Array <Assignment> &);
};
```

Student.cpp:

```
void Student::setStudent(int a,int b,string c){
this->ID = a;
    this->group = b;
    this->name = c;
}
```

The error I get is the fallowing:

```
D:\c++\Begin\Lab6-8_UML/Domain.h:70:2: error: 'class Assignment'
                                       has no member named 'setStudent'`
```

EDIT:

```
template <class T>
struct Array{
    int lenght;
    T * M;

    Array( int size ) : lenght(size), M(new T[size])
    {
    }
    ~Array()
    {
       delete[] M;
    }
};
```

Comment: This error is not directly related to the use of templates. See how much you can reduce the program without the problem going away.

Comment: the declaration of the `Array` class could be helpful too.

Comment: I don't understand why `addStudent` is a template function. It requires `setStudent`, which only seems applicable to your `Student` class, so you might as well only take an `Array<Student>`. As an added benefit: regular type errors are easier to decode.

Answer (score 1):

It is not visible in the code you provided, but I suspect you are calling somewhere `addStudent<T>` function with an `Array<Assignment>` parameter (the last one) and that the `Assignment` class has no `setStudent` method.

Comment: i think it is the same but the hole process of calling is here i displayed it form initialisating to declaring... thanks anyhow ihope i`mm find the source of the error soon..